# Kакой компилятор использовался при компиляции операционной системы Windows 7?

Tags: windows, компилятор

Kакой компилятор использовался  при компиляции операционной системы Windows? 
Как это происходит и где он храниться (В пустоте?)

Comment: В более старой версии Windows 7, например?

Comment: Очевидно, что минимум компилятор для c++ и для c#. А тебе собственно зачем? `Как это происходит и где он храниться (В пустоте?)` Ммм... ну статью на Википедии про компиляторы ты хотя бы прочёл?

Comment: Просто интересно как это все работает на  низах

Answer (score 6):

Windows - не монолитный проект, собираемый одним определенным набором инструментов. Но большая часть кода Windows, написанная на С и С++, собирается с помощью Microsoft Visual C++. Это можно легко понять по так называемой [Rich-сигнатуре](https://www.ntcore.com/files/richsign.htm), которую компоновщик Visual C++ добавляет во все выходные PE-файлы между DOS-заголовком и заголовком PE. Есть и другие признаки - например, импорт функций из msvcrt.dll (стандартной библиотеки C из Visual C++); хотя само ядро их не импортирует и имеет свою, статически скомпонованную версию CRT.

Какова же версия Visual C++? Для определения (на примере ядра - ntoskrnl.exe) этого войдем в командную строку разработчика Visual Studio и выполним команду

```
dumpbin "%systemroot%\system32\ntoskrnl.exe" /headers
```

Результат:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe

PE signature found

File Type: EXECUTABLE IMAGE

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
              18 number of sections
        5D673542 time date stamp Thu Aug 29 07:15:30 2019
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
              22 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses

OPTIONAL HEADER VALUES
             20B magic # (PE32+)
            9.00 linker version
          4AE200 size of code
          11F400 size of initialized data
            3600 size of uninitialized data
          2A2AE0 entry point (00000001402A2AE0)
            1000 base of code
       140000000 image base (0000000140000000 to 00000001405DCFFF)
            1000 section alignment
             200 file alignment
            6.01 operating system version
            6.01 image version
            6.01 subsystem version
               0 Win32 version
          5DD000 size of image
             600 size of headers
          558155 checksum
               1 subsystem (Native)
               0 DLL characteristics
           80000 size of stack reserve
            2000 size of stack commit
          100000 size of heap reserve
            1000 size of heap commit
               0 loader flags
              10 number of directories
          528000 [   10B09] RVA [size] of Export Directory
          5A0B80 [      78] RVA [size] of Import Directory
          5A2000 [   34570] RVA [size] of Resource Directory
          274000 [   28368] RVA [size] of Exception Directory
          549A00 [    21D0] RVA [size] of Certificates Directory
          5D7000 [    2130] RVA [size] of Base Relocation Directory
            1390 [      1C] RVA [size] of Debug Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Architecture Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Global Pointer Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Thread Storage Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Load Configuration Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Bound Import Directory
            1000 [     388] RVA [size] of Import Address Table Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Delay Import Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of COM Descriptor Directory
               0 [       0] RVA [size] of Reserved Directory
```

Нас интересует поле linker version - оно равно 9.00, что соответствует Visual Studio 2008 (см [таблицу версий Visual C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B#Internal_version_numbering)).

Можно более подробно определить версию вплоть до номера сборки, а также какое количество объектных файлов было скомпилировано каким компилятором, если воспользоваться программой для чтения вышеупомянутой недокументированной Rich-сигнатуры: https://github.com/dishather/richprint

Передавая ей ntoskrnl.exe, получаем:

```
@comp.id   id version count   description
00837809   83  30729   119 [ C ] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
00937809   93  30729    13 [IMP] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
00010000    1      0   150 [---] Unmarked objects
00957809   95  30729    81 [ASM] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
00897809   89  30729   848
00847809   84  30729    27 [C++] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
00927809   92  30729     1 [EXP] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
00947809   94  30729     1
00917809   91  30729     1 [LNK] VS2008 SP1 build 30729
```

Таким образом, ядро Windows 7 было собрано Visual C++ 9.0 build 30729 (Visual Studio 2008 SP1). Большая часть объектных файлов была скомпилирована компилятором С, меньше - MASM. (На машине, где производился анализ, Windows 7 SP1 Version 6.1.7601)

Comment: А то что используется `masm` по каким-то признакам определяется?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Только по значению compid, которые расшифровал автор richprint. Вот здесь: https://github.com/dishather/richprint/blob/master/comp_id.txt#L202 - под [ASM] видимо понимается Ассемблер в составе Visual C++, т.е. MASM

Comment: мм.. да, что-то я невнимательно ответ прочитал... как-то данные `richprint`'а совсем просмотрел...